# How to make dragscroll plugin work after an ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax request where I load html code on it, its a slider of images with a class called dragscroll (its a js plugin that need this class to make it dragable https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll) when this piece of code is loaded by ajax it wont work, is it possible after ajax load make js work with the new content generated?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style type="text/css">
    ul {
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      overflow-x: auto;

    }

    ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
      background: transparent;
    }

    li {
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

  </style>
</head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-5">
          <ul class="dragscroll">
            <li>
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/172/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/173/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/174/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/175/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/176/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/177/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/178/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/179/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/180/200/300">
            </li>
            <li class="li">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/181/200/300">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button id="loadAjax" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Load Ajax</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-5" id="ajaxContent">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://asvd.github.io/dragscroll/dragscroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#loadAjax').on( "click", function() {
          $.ajax({
            type:'GET',

            success: function(){
              data = '<ul class="dragscroll">';
              data += '<li>';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/172/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/173/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/174/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/175/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/176/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/177/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/178/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/179/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/180/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '<li class="li">';
              data += '<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/181/200/300">';
              data += '</li>';
              data += '</ul>';
              data += '</div>';

              $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
            }
          }); 
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the js responsible for the slider is inited on window load event. So it won't get initialized on any html fragment, which get to the DOM after the page already loaded. You should manually initialize the plugin after you appended the new fragment to the DOM.

Based on the repo you linked, you should do something like:

> If you add or remove the dragscroll class dynamically, invoke dragscroll.reset() to update the listeners.

Comment: it works however, can be a bad practice reload the js again every time I load something with ajax?

Comment: Well, the library you are using doesn't really have any other option. If you check out for example this plugin https://github.com/markembling/jquery-gpopover-plugin, it has an option to manually initialize a new popover on an element, however the plugin you are using can only reinit the whole page. It is unlikely to lead to any performance issues though.